# Filtering strings

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'am trying to filter a string with Regex.Replace, but I'am stuck on Replacing text like this: [02] or [06].

The code I'am using now is:

```
string cleanData = Regex.Replace(stringtext, "[..]", "");
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: please provide example input string, and the desired output, otherwise it is not clear what you are looking for

Comment: this is my input string: [15]
[06]
[02]PZ325353;13
59120102;NL120
0000002 ;w4[03]
[02]PB
014EC8F;135930
124124;asdfsadfsdf
asdfs ;asdfsadf[03]
[15]
[06]

Comment: Are you interested to replace brackets and its containment with empty string?

Comment: yes, because the [02] and [06] etc needs to be stripped, I only need to strip the P and Ñ from it, does anybody know the regex for single characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
string cleanData = Regex.Replace(stringtext, @"\[..\]", "");
```

(cannot test it).

Comment: Nice, almost, just had to Add an "@" in front of the double quotes, thanks for your help! EDIT: the code you Edited is correct, thank you